# Show documentation pane within IntelliJ window

Tags: intellij-idea, documentation, javadoc

I used to have a pane on the side of the IntelliJ 2019.3 window showing [Javadoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) for currently selected class name. That pane has disappeared. How do I get it back?

[image: screenshot of Javadoc displayed in IntelliJ pane]

I found this [*Code reference information*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html) page on the IntelliJ site, but it does not help. It shows a "gear" icon in the *Quick documentation* [windoid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/windoid) that might do the trick. My my IntelliJ offers no such "gear" icon.

Comment: Please upload your `Quick Documentation` window screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select the name of a class in the source editor pane.
2. Choose `View` > `Quick Documentation`.

The pane appears on the bottom right of the IntelliJ window.

Choosing `View` > `Quick Definition` (rather than `Quick Documentation`) shows the documentation in a windoid. To fill the pane on the side, choose `View` > `Quick Documentation` as described in step # 2 above.